# How can I check if a string has two words with a hyphen between them?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var hyphens = myString.Split('-');
topTitle = hyphens[0].Replace("_", " ");
subTitle = hyphens[1].Replace("_", " ");
```

This is working but if myString does not have two words with a hyphen between them I get an error. How can I make it such that if the myString contains only one word then topTitle gets that word and subTitle gets "n/a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Regex, but changing your code a little bit helps also.

```
var hyphens = myString.Split('-');
topTitle = hyphens[0].Replace("_", " ");
subTitle = hyphens.Length > 1 ? hyphens[1].Replace("_", " ") : "n/a";
```

Just check the `Length`, if it's less than one show them "n/a" like you want.

Answer (score 5):

You should check `if (hyphens.Length == 2)` after you split it. Any length other than 2 means you do not have two words.

Comment: the `.Length` option is what I would go for